# Create an array include email

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function to extract email to send but I do not find the solution

Thank you

email type : `contact<contact@contact.com>, contact1<contact1@contact.com>`

the function

```
 public static function extractEmail(string $email)
    {
      $pattern = '/(?<=<)(.*?)+(?=\>)/';
      $result = preg_match_all($pattern , $email , $matches);


      $result = explode(',', $result);

      if (is_array($result)) {
       foreach ($result as $token) {
        $email = filter_var(filter_var($token, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

          if ($email !== false) {
            $emails[] = $email;
          }
        }

        return $emails[0];
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

and after I make a loop via foreach.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? You should be getting multiple notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) and [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) to sanitize email addresses and remove invalid ones:

```
/**
 * @return string[]
 */
function extractEmails(string $contactString): array
{
    if (!preg_match_all('/<(?<emails>[^>]+)>/', $contactString, $matches)) {
        return [];
    }

    return array_filter(array_map(static function (string $email): ?string {
        $sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        
        return filter_var($sanitizedEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? $sanitizedEmail : null;
    }, $matches['emails']));
}
```

Usage:

```
print_r(extractEmails('contact<contact@contact.com>, contact1<contact1@contact.com>'));
// ['contact@contact.com', 'contact1@contact.com']
```

Basically:

- `preg_match_all` gathers all (supposed) email addresses within `$matches['email']`
- `array_map` sanitizes and validates said email addresses (`null` is returned if one is invalid)
- `array_filter` finally removes all `null` values.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/chNjn)**